# Proxy for MSGraph APIs

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an adapter (WEB API that will act as a pass through) 
for invoking the MS Graph APIs for managing my Active Directory.

AD objects like application and users will be customized to meet our application needs (removing some attributes, adding some extension attributes etc.) and a transformation from our application specific object to AD object would happen in our adapter layer before and after calling MS Graph APIs.

MS Graph APIs [currently supports OData queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters). 
Applications and users would be read as page-wise.
If I have to provide the same OData options in my pass thru Web API layer, how can I do that?

i.e.

- API A supports OData queries.
- API B calls the methods that support OData queries in API A.
- API B is exposed to the client. When the client calls the method from API B
   with OData `$Filter`, the result has to be returned.

How can I support the OData options in API B?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure I get your question correctly but, from what I understand, you just want to proxy the API calls to MS Graph and make some changes on the fly to the response.

OData queries are just simple query parameters (see the [OData tutorial](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/)). So, basically, you just have to get those query parameters in your proxy and forward them to the MS Graph. The response you'll get will then be compliant with the original query.

However, depending on how you mangle the data, you may end up not being compliant with the user query. For example:

- The user made a `$select(Id)` query, but your logic add a custom property `Foo`. The user just wanted `Id` but you added `Foo` anyway.
- The user made an `$orderby Name asc` query, but your logic modify the property `Name`. It may not be ordered after your logic.
- The user wants to make `$filter` query on the `Foo` property. MS Graph will complain because it doesn't know the `Foo` property.
- Etc.

If you want to handle that cases, well, you'll have to parse the different OData queries and adapt your logic accordingly. `$orderby`, `$top`/`$skip`, `$count`, `$expand` and `$select` should be pretty straight-forward ; `$filter` and `$search` would require a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I was looking for a solution to this.
https://community.apigee.com/questions/8642/how-do-we-fetch-the-query-parameters-odata-standar.html

Instead of parsing the URL to get the OData query parameters, i wanted to understand the standard method to process the OData requests.
Now I am doing the below to extract the OData query parameters and passing them to MSGraph API.
string strODataQuery = String.Join("&", HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith("$")) .Select(kvp => String.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value))));

And I am performing the conversions after retrieving the results.

Regards